# How can I add a default value for null values when using string_agg in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have this in a select query:

```
  string_agg(CAST('(' || item.name || ', price:' || item.price || ')' AS text), ' ') as item_price,
```

and sometimes the price is null and I want to it to just default to `'TBD'`. Is there a way to just do something like `item.price OR "TBD"` or somehow add a default value without adding a default to the price column?

Comment: Lookup the COALESCE function for your database, as you mention several in your tags. 
It returns the first non-null expression, so you can do COALESCE(item.price, 'TBD') instead of item.price.

Comment: @SQLRaptor that doesn't seem to work with the CAST and it seems to be looking for a "TBD" column on item

Comment: It's a matter of the wrong string delimiter character. 
What DBMS are you using?

Comment: @SQLRaptor postgres

Answer (score 0):

Use `COALESCE()`:

```
string_agg(CAST('(' || item.name || ', price:' || COALESCE(item.price, 'TBD') || ')' AS text), ' ') as item_price,
```

You may need to cast to a string, depending on the type:

```
string_agg(CAST('(' || item.name || ', price:' || COALESCE(item.price::text, 'TBD') || ')' AS text), ' ') as item_price,
```

Answer (score 0):

You should you the COALESCE function. This will return 'TBD' is the value of item.price is NULL. Use it like this:

```
string_agg(CAST('(' || item.name || ', price:' || COALESCE(item.price, 'TBD') || ')' AS text), ' ') as item_price,
```

Answer (score 0):

The SQL **Coalesce** function is used to handle NULL values. During the expression evaluation process the NULL values are replaced with the user-defined value.

The SQL Coalesce function evaluates the arguments in order and always returns first non-null value from the defined argument list.

In your case the usage of the function would be:

```
string_agg(CAST('(' || item.name || ', price:' || COALESCE(item.price, 'TBD') || ')' AS text), ' ') as item_price,
```